# How to add multiple product to magento cart from outside of magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, cart, shopping-cart, external

I have to add multiple items into magento cart from out side of magento (external website), through `/path/to/app/checkout/cart/add?product=[id]&qty=[qty]` this method I can add one product to the cart.

Can anyone suggest how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way, but you cannot add quantities to the rest of the products. They will be added in minimum qty. (most probably 1).

```
/checkout/cart/add/?product=[id]&qty=[qty]&related_product=[id2],[id3],...,[idN]
```

It works even if products with ids `id2, .., idN` are not actually related products to the main product.
Click this for demo:http://demo.magentocommerce.com/checkout/cart/add/?product=51&qty=2&related_product=17,18.

But be careful. In ce1.8 this doesn't work. Actually just adding a simple product to the cart doesn't work anymore (I mean this `checkout/cart/add?product=[id]&qty=[qty]`). Starting with this version the `form_key` is required when adding something to the cart.
Since this `form_key` depends on the session you may want to create your own controller and action that receives the products to be added to the cart and redirects to `checkout/cart/add?product=[id]&qty=[qty]&form_key=FORM_KEY_HERE`

Comment: www.abc.com/checkout/cart/add/?product=1&qty=1 :: is right what i did?

Comment: this does not work in 1.8 or above. In 1.7 it should

Comment: Could you pls suggest me, which way can i add bulk products to customer add to cart. my ver 1.9.2.3

Comment: its working 1.9.2.3, how can i multiple products.

Comment: bro I tried multiple combinations, its not working,, could you pls help me

Answer (score 1):

It might not be the easiest way and might be difficult to maintain on magento updates but you could add your own controller. Ideally one that extends the core `Mage_Checkout_CartController`, but call yours from a new router. Then you could add your own function that uses the core functionality to add products but just takes in a customized format of parameters.

**Config.xml**

```
<routers>
    <new_checkout>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
             <module>New_Checkout</module>
             <frontName>new-checkout</frontName>
        </args>
    </new_checkout>
</routers>
```

**New_Checkout_CartController**

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';

class New_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    public function addMultipleAction() {
        $cart = $this->_getCart();
        //Loop through each set of parameters for a products
        $product =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->load($productId);
        $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
        $cart->save();
    }
}
```

If you send the parameters in a way that each individual product is the same as the core cart expects than the addProduct function will work well.

**Note** There is no error checking in my basic example but I would recommend adding them. Look through the core controller to see how it works and mirror that when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, please check it out. Taken from http://deepakbhatta.com/magento-add-multiple-items-to-cart/

How to adds multiple items to shopping cart, at a time?

Normally this code is kept into controller.

```
<?php
class Packagename_Modulename_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
  public function multipleProdAddAction()
  {
    $items = array("1" => "sku1" , "2" => "sku2");
    $invalidProduct = array();
    $validProducts = array();
    foreach($items as $qty=>$sku) {
        $id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
        //Check whether the sku exists or not.
        if(!$id) {
            $invalidProduct[$sku] = $id;
        }
        else {
            $validProducts[$sku] = $quantity;
        }

    }
    //If any of the product we are adding, is not valid, we are not adding it to cart.
    if(count($invalidProduct) < 1 && count($validProducts) > 0) {
        try{
            $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();
            $ms="";
            foreach($validProducts as $sku => $qty) {
                $params = array('qty' => $qty);
                $id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($sku);
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);;
                $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
                $msg .= $product->getName(). " is successfully added into cart<br>";
            }
             $cart->save();
             Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('checkout')->__($msg));
             $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');

        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError(Mage::helper('checkout')->__($e->getMessage()));
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
     }

    }  
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Its not working,,  $items = array("1" => "#1" , "2" => "#2");

Comment: my code : https://justpaste.it/1ebg3